# MySQL PROCEDURE code seems to run but doesn't do anything

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

this is an assignment our professor left us and even though there are better ways to fill the tables with data he wanted us to do it this way.

I have these code of a stored procedure, which seems to run but I can't figure out why it doesn't add the data to the tables.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fillSaleLogs;
DELIMITER ^^
CREATE PROCEDURE fillSaleLogs(IN amountOfDays INT, IN operationtype INT, IN maxSalesPerDay INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE nextSunday INT;
    DECLARE recordTime TIMESTAMP;
    DECLARE maxSalesPerDay INT;
    DECLARE salesPerDay INT;
    DECLARE chosenProduct INT;
    DECLARE chosenCart INT;
    DECLARE chosenCashier INT;
    DECLARE chosenPaymentMethod INT;
    DECLARE chosenBeach INT;
    DECLARE chosenComission INT;
    DECLARE price INT;
    DECLARE cashUsed INT;
    DECLARE quantity INT;
    DECLARE soldQuantity int;
    DECLARE temp int;

    WHILE amountOfDays > 0 DO
        SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -FLOOR(RAND() * 6) MONTH) + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 86400) SECOND AS random_timestamp INTO recordTime;
        SET salesPerDay = RAND() * maxSalesPerDay;
        SELECT idCopero FROM coperos ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 INTO chosenCashier;
        SELECT idCarrito FROM carritos ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 INTO chosenCart;
        SELECT TipoPago FROM Ventas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 INTO chosenPaymentMethod;
        SELECT idPlaya FROM playas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 INTO chosenBeach;
        SELECT idComision FROM comisiones ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 INTO chosenComission;
        SET cashUsed = price + RAND()*5000;
        
        
        WHILE salesPerDay > 0 DO
            SELECT idProducto FROM productos ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 INTO chosenProduct;
            SELECT idPrecio FROM precios WHERE idProducto = chosenProduct.idProducto INTO price;
            INSERT INTO ventas (tipoPago, monto, vuelto, fecha, idCopero, idCarrito, idPlaya, idProducto, idComision) VALUES
            (chosenPaymentMethod, cashUsed, cashUsed - price, recordTime, chosenCashier, chosenCart, chosenBeach, chosenProduct, chosenComission);
            -- TODO: Actualizar cantidades de ingredientes
            SELECT COUNT(idIngrediente) as quantity from ingredientesxproducto WHERE idProducto = chosenProduct INTO quantity;
            WHILE quantity > 0 DO
                INSERT INTO inventoryCheck (posttime, idFirstCheck, idCheckTypes) VALUES
                (recordTime, chosenCashier, 3);
                
                SELECT cantidadIngrediente FROM ingredientesxproducto WHERE idProducto = chosenProduct INTO temp;
                SET soldQuantity = selledQuantity - temp;
                
                INSERT INTO inventoryLog (posttime, idIngrediente, idProducto, idInventoryCheck, cantidadIngrediente) VALUES
                (recordTime, quantity, chosenProduct, IDENT_CURRENT('inventoryCheck'), cantidadIngrediente);
            END WHILE;
            -- Actualizar dinero en la caja
            SET salesPerDay = salesPerDay - 1;
        END WHILE;
        SET amountOfDays = amountOfDays - 1;
    END WHILE;
END^^
DELIMITER ;

CALL fillSaleLogs(3, 2, 5);
```

Here you can check out the model: [Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcMB1.png)

And here is the output after running the query: [0 rows affected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykAB1.png)

Comment: The rows-affected information isn't reliable except immediately after a literal DML statement (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE).  (I, for one, never rely on it without *rigorous* testing and only if there's no other way to get that data. ) Do you know whether your rows made it into your table? SELECT * FROM ventas` and other tables will tell you. Please [edit] your question to tell us that.

Comment: 1) You have declared `maxSalesPerDay` twice.
2) Your `while` loop will never exit.